# Ubuntu - Sequential file naming with User input

Tags: ubuntu, unix, input, terminal, filenames

I am trying to create a custom command for renaming image sequences.

I am studying Visual Effects and sometimes have to rename files sequentially.

I want to navigate to the directory where the images are saved, call the command, receive a prompt to enter a prefix for the file name (EG. {PREFIX}_%04d.png), and execute the command after entering said prefix.

Now I know from another post that I can rename files sequentially via:

```
for i in *.jpg; do
    p=$(printf "USERINPUTHERE_%04d.jpg" ${n})
    mv ${i} ${p}
    let n=n+1
done
```

But I am not sure how or if it’s possible to have the command request input before fully executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat cmd.sh 
#!/bin/bash

create_file()
{
    echo hello > "$1"
    echo "created $1"
}

format()
{
    printf "%s_%04d.jpg" "$1" "$2"
}

read -p "enter prefix: " PREFIX
i=1
FILE="$(format "$PREFIX" "$i")"
while [ -e "$FILE" ]; do
    ((i++))
    FILE="$(format "$PREFIX" "$i")"
done
create_file "$FILE"
$ ./cmd.sh 
enter prefix: hello
created hello_0001.jpg
$ ./cmd.sh 
enter prefix: hello
created hello_0002.jpg
$ ./cmd.sh
enter prefix: world
created world_0001.jpg
$ ./cmd.sh
enter prefix: hello
created hello_0003.jpg
$ ls *.jpg
hello_0001.jpg  hello_0002.jpg  hello_0003.jpg  world_0001.jpg
```

You can have `create_file()` do whatever you need, and `format()` format the filename however you feel like.

Also note that this is a very underoptimized implementation. If you plan to have many files, then it would be better to remember the last created file for each prefix.

All that said, it would be more useful to accept the file name as an argument instead of prompting for it, because then you can easily use your command in scripts.

Comment: Understood. Yes the under optimized option would not work when working with sequences of 100+ images. The file name as an argument sounds like the way I would want to go. So is the idea to have the argument create the prefix first and then call the rest of the command to add the sequential numbering to each file?

Comment: Yes. Essentially just replace the line `read -p "enter prefix: " PREFIX` with `PREFIX="$1"`.